# flag provided but not defined: -rpc

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, private-blockchain

I'm using Geth to set up a private ethereum network and this is the command:

```
$ geth --identity "MyTestNode" --datadir "SomeDir" init genesis.json --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" --rpcport "8000" --rpccorsdomain "*" --port "30303" --nodiscover --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --autodag --networkid 1900 --nat "any" console
```

But I'm getting that -rpc is provided but not defined and I don't know if everything else is correct.

Comment: The `init` and `console` are geth commands, you can only use once per geth invocation. You should split your command in two invocations: `geth [params] init genesis.json`, and then `geth [other params] console`

Comment: The above comment is correct and should be submitted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In **GETH** service the init and console are commands, you can't execute them togueter.
you should use the **init** first then the **console**

i left a image about the geth structure

[image: geth-structure]

Answer (score 0):

rpc is replaced by http in stable version

With all rpc options replaced by their http equivalent:

--rpc => --http

--rpcapi => --http.api

--rpccorsdomain => --http.corsdomain